# Pass JS variable to controller and view in Yii

Tags: javascript, php, yii, parameter-passing

I am new to Yii. I have a javascript variable. This ID must be passed to the controller and to the respective view also. I have a problem in accessing the JS variable in the controller. Please help me. If the JS variable is passed, how will I check the passed variable.? Thanks in advance,

My view from where JS variable(id) is passed:

```
<div style="float:left;padding-left:20px;">
                    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'host_customer_id'); ?>
                    <?php 
                    echo $form->textField($model,'host_customer_id',array('style'=>'width:420px;'));
                    $this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2', array(
                        'selector' => '#NimsoftHost_host_customer_id',
                        'options' => array(
                            'allowClear'=>false,
                            'placeholder' => 'Search Other Customers',
                            'minimumInputLength' => 3,
                            'quietMillis'=>100,
                            'ajax' => array(
                                'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl('Nimsoft/customers'),
                                'dataType' => 'jsonp',
                                'data' => 'js: function(term,page) {
                                        return {
                                            q: term, 
                                            //ctype: $("#itsmIncidents_cloudcustomer input:radio:checked").val(),
                                            page_limit: 10,
                                        };
                                    }',
                                'results' => 'js: function(data,page){
                                    return {results: data.details};
                                }',
                            ),

                             'formatResult'  => 'js:function(data){
                                return data.name;
                              }',
                            'formatSelection' => 'js: function(data) {
                                return data.name;
                            }',

                        ),
                    ));
                    ?>
                    <div style="float:right;padding-left:10px;">
                        <?php 
                        echo CHtml::link('view details', array('/Nimsoft/ciLink'), array(
                        'onclick'=>'return hs.htmlExpand(this, { objectType: "iframe", wrapperClassName: "full-size",height:500, align: "center" } )',
                            'class'=>'btn btn-block btn-success',
                            'style'=>'width:100px;display:none;',
                            'id'=>'customer_details_pop',
                         ));
                        ?>
                   </div>
                 </div>


<?php $this->endWidget();?>

<script>
$("#NimsoftHost_host_customer_id").on("change", function(e) { 
         <?php echo CHtml::ajax(array(
            'url'=>array('Nimsoft/loadCustType'),
            'data'=> "js:{'NimsoftHost[host_customer_id]':e.val}",
            'type'=>'post',
            'dataType'=>'json',
            'success'=>"function(data)
            {

                // enable customer link
                $('#customer_details_pop').css('display','block');
                $('#customer_details_pop').attr('href', 'Nimsoft/details/'+data.customerid);
} ",
        ))?>;
     })
</script>
```

here I am passing data.customerid. I want to know this value goes to controller or not. If it goes, how to print that in my view(details.php).

My controller action:

```
public function actionDetails()
        {
          $this->render('details');
        }
```

Comment: The data.customerid in the url will be a querystring not a session variable. Do you know about the urlManager?

Comment: I have changed my code, please say now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your customerId variable should be passed as a query string.

**For example:**

The url in your link should be:

```
 $('#customer_details_pop').attr('href', 'Nimsoft/details/id/'+data.customerid);
```

and in your controller you can retrieve the id with ...

```
public function actionDetails($id)
{
   $this->render('details',array('customerId'=>$id));
}
```

For more info please read the following on [Yii documentation on Url Management](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url)

Comment: It gives me an error: 
Error 400
Your request is invalid.

Comment: is it enough if I write echo $id; in view?

Comment: Does your urlManager config item in protected/config/main.php have the following entry? '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',

Comment: Ya its having the same.

Comment: Thanks, I got the ID, it gives me 45c48cce2e2d7fbdea1afc51c7c6ad26, and this value is no where related to the customer, what to do?

Comment: Use console.log(data) to check what data is returning in your ajax success response.